# Best way to start a "PC booking" application in Windows 7 / Vista?

Tags: c#, shell, windows-7, explorer, winlogon

I'm writing a kind of PC booking application (client in C#) and all is done except that I have problems to start it as soon as possible when a user log on to the PC (Windows 7 / Vista), i.e. I want to override explorer.exe in some kind of way.

I have tried to replace my app with explorer.exe in,

“HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell”

and it works, but when I try to start explorer.exe within my app,

```
const string explorer = "explorer.exe";
string explorerPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WINDIR"), explorer);
Process eProcess = new Process();
eProcess.StartInfo.FileName = explorerPath;
eProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
eProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
eProcess.Start();
eProcess.WaitForInputIdle();
```

it just hangs and doesn't start explorer as it should.

I also tried lot of other "workarounds" to start with different registry entries according to,

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee851671.aspx

but none seems to work 100% in Windows 7 / Vista. In XP it seems to work better.

BTW: UAC is turned off on all machines this will run on.

Any suggestions would be nice - right now I'm stuck.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have time to play and provide a real answer, but the "UseShellExecute" setting looks wrong to me - the shell is normally explorer (except in your case I guess it's your program), which isn't running yet, so it's not likely to be able to start itself. Have you tried setting this to false?

Comment: Hi Tao. Yes - I've thought about that too and have tried to set UseShellExecute to false. I do get an explorer window now, but no shell, no taskbar and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Don't `eProcess.WaitForInputIdle();`, it'll work then.

Comment: It also seems to work if I set[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced] SeparateProcess to 1.

Comment: Hacking around in the registry is an extremely bad idea, the reason your app was hanging was because of the call I mentioned above, which blocks on a certain condition I'm pretty sure explorer.exe never gets to. Why must your app start before Explorer, anyway? I'm pretty sure that's a dangerous thing to mess around with on Windows... the first explorer instance does a lot more than you think it does, and altering how it starts up with Windows is not a good idea.

Comment: Well SpikeX it's a PCBooking application and the user shouldn't be able to start anything before I lock the keyboard, disable CAD, taskmanager and so on. It's the whole idea with this app.

Comment: Ah, I see, just curious. In that case, yeah, that's probably the best route. :)

Comment: No, it doesn't work as I want. I do get an explorer window, but no shell, no taskbar, desktop and so on. I have to try another approach.

Comment: Explorer may have logic inside of it to detect its parent process, and if some condition isn't satisfied, it opens a standard explorer window instead of setting up the desktop and taskbar. Try starting it using a proxy - invoke a new command prompt (with `CreateNoWindow` enabled, so it's hidden), and call "start explorer.exe".